# Spire.Barcode printing barcode from string

Tags: c#, barcode, barcode-printing

I can't manage with my problem with barcode. I'am passing the string from my file in Excel for example 51453125312453. And I'am using Spire.Barcode in my model like this

```
private void GenerateBarcode()
    {
        BarcodeSettings st = new Spire.Barcode.BarcodeSettings();
        st.Code128SetMode = Spire.Barcode.Code128SetMode.Auto;
        //st.Data = Ilosc.ToString("F6") + "*" + Partia;
        st.TextFont = new System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 16);
        st.ShowTopText = false;
        st.ShowTextOnBottom = true;
        st.ImageWidth = 100;
        Spire.Barcode.BarCodeGenerator bg = new Spire.Barcode.BarCodeGenerator(st);
        HeaderBarcode = bg.GenerateImage().ToString();
        //bg.GenerateImage();
    }
```

and my string

```
private string headerBarcode;
    public string HeaderBarcode
    {
        get
        {
            return headerBarcode;
        }
        set
        {
            if (headerBarcode != value)
            {
                headerBarcode = value;
                GenerateBarcode();
                NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(HeaderBarcode));
            }
        }
    }
```

and in my print preview a have this
System.Drawing.Bitmap instead of barcode. Could you help me to make this right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error in this line:

```
HeaderBarcode = bg.GenerateImage().ToString();
```

GenerateImage() - returns Bitmap, so when you try to convert Bitmap to string you get a name of class System.Drawing.Bitmap.

You need save as image and open it.

```
bg.GenerateImage().Save("Barcode.png");
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("Barcode.png");
```

Comment: ok but what about this string HeaderBarcode? Where this barcode should take this string to generate?